# Was Huttese based on Klingon?

Tags: star-wars, star-trek, languages, klingon-language

I came across the below image '[Huttese](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Huttese)' script from *Star Wars*:

[image: Poster in Huttese]

It struck me immediately as bearing a strong resemblance to Klingon script:

[image: Klingon text sample]

So, my question is, **is there any evidence to suggest that Huttese script was based on Klingon script?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Probably No.

The script in your question uses **Nal-Huttese** characters:

[image]

These are a calligraphic form of Huttese, in contrast to **Trade Huttese**:

[image]

Both were created around 1997 for use in *The Phantom Menace*.

While Trade Huttese has nothing in common with Klingon characters, Nal-Huttese has a slight resemblance — but it is perhaps only very slight and the low-resolution, slightly pixelated image in the original question creates an illusion that they are more similar than they actually are.

As seen into the chart above, Nal-Huttese characters are more jagged than Klingon ones (see "H", "2", "3" etc).  Also, many Nal-Huttese characters are broken into more than once piece (see "A", "B", "J", etc).

Contrast this to the Klingon alphabet:

[image]

We don't see the jaggedness of Huttese (the Klingon characters flow with brushstrokes) and only a couple of Klingon characters are broken.

I would argue that there is no alarming similarity between the two, and both are generally "alien" in the broad scope of science fiction.

Finally, the Klingon alphabet was invented in 1979 for use in *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*, and then further refined for repeated use in *The Search for Spock* and *The Voyage Home*, and so it predates the cinematic invention of Huttese characters by almost two decades.  However, as ThePopMachine said, there is no absolutely evidence to suggest that art designers for *The Phantom Menace* were influenced by Klingon.

All in all, they seem to have been aiming for "alien" more so than "Klingon", and wound up with a somewhat similar finished product.

This doesn't mean that there *wasn't* a conscious or subconscious attempt to imitate Klingon characters — just not one that we know of or have evidence for.

Comment: That Huttese chart seems extremely bizarre. The alphabet stops at s? Only numbers 1, 2, and 3? Is the rest just not known, or is there supposed to be some in-universe reason for why exactly those characters are missing?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think it's an out-of-universe deficiency: simply that these were the characters necessary for the specific appearances of Huttese in *The Phantom Menace*.

Answer (score 4):

## No.

I've been looking and haven't found any connection,  so I'm going to go out on a limb and say there's no evidence.

[Written Huttese](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Huttese_(writing_system)) was created for 1999's *The Phantom Menace*, so the potential is that it was influenced by modern written Klingon.

Whereas regarding written [Klingon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_alphabets):

> The Astra Image Corporation designed the symbols (currently used to "write" Klingon) for Star Trek: The Motion Picture, although these symbols are often incorrectly attributed to Michael Okuda.[1] They based the letters on the Klingon battlecruiser hull markings (three letters) first created by Matt Jeffries, and on Tibetan writing because the script had sharp letter forms—used as a testament to the Klingons' love for bladed weapons.

This dates written Klingon to 1979 or earlier.

However, there's still no connection, and if there were,  it might not be discussed explicitly due to potential intellectual property implications.

Comment: ... but when @Praxis proves me wrong,  I will happily delete.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to prove you right. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I can see the resemblence you mean but but its not based on each other.

Both scripts do however have resamblances to japanese characters, so parts of both scripts possibly stem from the same set of characters, mamking them look similiar.